# C# - Copy to Clipboard from First Time

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy-paste

I wrote a Program that i paste some of Rows in dataGridView and do some Processing on this data and then copy this data. But when i copy this data from dataGridView, if the data is Small number of Rows Such as 5 Rows it Takes 9 times of pressing copy to copy data to Clipboard, if the number of Rows is 10 it takes 4 times of Pressing copy to Copy, if the Rows is larger than 25 it works from First time!

```
         dgData.SelectAll();

        if (dgData.RowCount > 0)
        {
            var lastRow = dgData.Rows[dgData.RowCount - 1];
            lastRow.Selected = false;
        }
        DataObject d = dgData.GetClipboardContent();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(d, true);
```

where is Problem? can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: what's value of `SelectionMode`?

Comment: SelectionMode is EnableWithoutHeaderText

Comment: no that value..

Comment: Sorry `SelectionMode` value is `RowHeaderSelect`

Comment: what if you change `SelectionMode ` to `FullRowSelect` and `MultipleSlelect` to `False`

Comment: this exception occurs **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.**

Comment: suggest also set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false, and your code no longer need exclude the last row specially.

Comment: I tried it before but its not the problem and its not work so i added this if condition